# Want to apply for a new job during a probation time. Not sure how to update my CV

Tags: new-job, job-change, probation

I just moved to another city with my current job, and the job has 6 months of probation. I have been already working for 3 months. Now I realize that the job does not fit for me and I'm doing something that is not related to the position that I applied for.

I used to work as an Android developer before. When I applied for this job, they told me that I will work on a backend with Java. My first idea was to get some experiences on backend development, so, I can turn myself into a full-stack mobile developer since I already know Android. They promised me that there will be a senior to teach me as well. In the first month, they asked me to make some automated UI tests for their website. In the second month, I wrote some Python scripts to export their database. In the third month, I did something with AWS stuff. And there is no senior to help me at all. Just other people who work as DevOps. I probably wrote only 100 lines of code in the past 3 months.

I feel like I'm doing some random things for them. I think If I still continue to work here, it will ruin my future and it will be difficult for me to apply for another job since I am not mastered at anything.

So, my problem is about updating my CV. As I mentioned before I already moved to another city and I still haven't updated my Linkedin profile yet(on my profile I'm still working in my previous company).
Should I change my address on my CV? Do I have to put my 3-month job on it as well? Or is it better not to change anything on my CV and tell the interviewer about my current situation?

Please help me. I really want to sort this out as soon as possible. The job is killing me every day.

Thank you so much.

Comment: what are you trying to communicate to recruiter/employers?

Answer (score 1):

### **Be honest with potential employers.**

I have never been on a hiring team, but I do not think wanting to leave your current job will reflect poorly on you. Here a few ideas for how to explain your current situation to potential employers:

- Tell them you are not doing the job you applied for (this is fairly common).
- Tell them your current job would be better suited for a recent college graduate, not an experienced developer like yourself.
- Tell them your current job is too easy, and you are looking for a job which challenges you (employers like hearing that).
- DO NOT complain you aren't getting trained by a senior dev. This makes it sound like you need assistance in your work.

The position you are in happens to people all the time. Don't forget that companies' primary goal is to get the best candidate. Unless you have a long history of leaving jobs after a few months, wanting to move on from a job you are over qualified for will not make you look bad.

Answer (score 1):

Probation time is there so that both the company and you yourself can decide whether you starting with this company was the right move, and if one of you thinks it's not, then either can quit the employment with a minimum of fuss.

So quitting during the probabition period is just normal. It is almost the same as going to an interview and not accepting the job offer.

So tell the new potential employer that you want to quit during your notice period. Give positive reasons why you are quitting. You are not given the work that you are hired for, you don't feel challenged.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have already made your decision about leaving this company. but take into consideration the fact that the world is not a perfect place and you 'mastering skills' is not what brings a company money. So Letting your supervisors understand the concerns you are having now and giving them the chance to correct it might save you a hastle. This doesn't guarantee you anything. But at least, its a calculated step that would show why you left and would leave you with a better proffessional relationship with your current company when you leave.

In case you decided to omit the fact that you worked at this company for 3 months, your recruiting company might ask you for a reference letter or for your ex boss's phone number. In that point in time,  you will either be represented poorly by a 3 months CV gap, or you would get caught lying about working 3 more months there.
So i think you have less to lose, by showing that you actually worked somewhere during these 3 months.

The first question on the head of recruiters would be, why did you leave? but talking honestly and showing them why you left (in this case a reason that shows you have a guenuine development drive) would let them think twice about repeating the problem you had with your current company, and would put you in a better light than compared to a 3 months jobless guy.